# Как в Django подключить viwes.py в urls.py

Tags: django

Стараюсь изучить Django (1.10.1) и пользуюсь записью с вебинара, но застрял на таком моменте, где не могу подключить вьюшку:

В проекте 2 папки: `MyBlog` и `blog`.
`MyBlog\urls.py` содержит:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

`blog\urls.py` содержит:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = ('',
   url(r'^$', blog.views.home, name='home'),
)
```

`blog\views.py` содержит:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

Я запутался, помогите. Понимаю что ошибка в файле `blog\urls.py` в строке:

```
urlpatterns = ('',
   url(r'^$', blog.views.home, name='home'),
)
```

При запуске коды выдает:

```
...
  File "G:\Proktor\Projects\MyBlog\blog\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'^$', blog.views.home, name='home'),
NameError: name 'blog' is not defined
```

Comment: А какую ошибку выдает? Приложите текст ошибки. А вообще у вас должно же быть `views.home`, разве нет?

Comment: Всё правильно. Разве, что только можно было бы сделать вот так: `urlpatterns = (url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
)`

Comment: @Flowneee дописал код ошибки. Если заменить `blog.views.home` на `views.home` то выдает ошибку: `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 420, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern '' is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
 HINT: Try removing the string ''. The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string as the first element.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).`

Comment: @МистерФикс вашу предложение мне помогло! Спасибо. Напишите ответ и я его отмечу как решение моего вопроса. (но так и не понял, почему заработало. И почему на записи вебинара предлагали именно так, как у меня записано, т.е. не рабочий вариант?)

Comment: @EmptyMan, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно. Разве, что только можно было бы сделать вот так:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
)
```